# Monogame C#: How can I go about creating a fixed grid of images that fit uniformly in each cell?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I want to create a grid that is divided up into cells, those cells will contain *images* that don't change their dimensions, but will fit uniformly inside each cell of the grid. My past attempts did not implement this concept, as the last attempt only used a list of vectors that was applied to an object's position; I was wondering how you would go about implementing these cells on the grid and then placing an image inside each cell, making sure the images don't adapt the dimensions of the cells.

```
//Previous vector attempt

public int _screenHeight;
public int _screenWidth;

_screenWidth = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth;
_screenHeight = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight;

public List<Vector2> generateGrid(int _rows, int _cols)
    {
        // Example list
        List<Vector2> gridPoints = new List<Vector2>();

        int rows = _rows;
        int cols = _cols;

        int units_x = _screenWidth / rows;
        int units_y = _screenHeight / cols;

        for (int i = 0; i < _cols; i++) 
            for (int j = 0; j < _rows; j++)
                gridPoints.Add(new Vector2(0 + units_x * j, 0 + units_y * i));

        // returns the vector points
        return gridPoints;
    }
```

My theory at the moment

- Create a cell class, which nests two rectangles(cell and image) together at defined points by basic division in the draw event.

[THEORY EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXwZ7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition in your previous attempt (the one in your post) was very close to what you were wanting to achieve.  Your logic for finding the `Vector2` positions was correct.

Since you already have the coordinates for your gridpoints, you can just put the `Texture2D`s on each gridpoint position.

By doing this, each `Texture2D` will have its upper-left corner be on the upper-left corner of the grid cell you assigned it to.

You also do not have to worry about the `Texture2D`s resizing to fit the grid cells.  Whenever you draw them, they will be drawn using the dimensions of the image file you provided them.

I.e. if you assigned a `153x45px` image to a `Texture2D`, then it will still be `153x45` pixels in size when it is drawn.  (That is, unless you changed its `scale`, but I'm assuming that you did not.)

If you want to have the `Texture2D` be *not* on the upper-left corner of the grid cell, then you must offset the `(X,Y)` coordinates by the amount of ***pixels*** you want it to be shifted.

E.g. shifting a `Texture2D` by 15 pixels down and 30 pixels to the right would require you to update its original position by `(X + 15, Y + 30)`.

Comment: Guess I didn't clarify well, my apologies. What I had intended was that each image would fit in a uniform manner inside each grid cell to prevent an unbalance in the space between the images (on the x-axis). Meaning that each image would be organized with even padding and without clipping outside the screen's bounds, or is there a better solution than what I had theorized?

Comment: @Eine, in that case, [this thread](http://community.monogame.net/t/resize-a-texture2d/8500/11) may help.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the grid  you just need to place the inner image centered in you cell.
Easiest approach is to use an offset. According to your example image you need to center it along the X -axis.

This means your X-offset would be

```
int offsetX = (cellWidth - imageWidth) / 2;
```

From there you can place you images using your grid points (assuming point 0,0 is the top left corner)by iterating through your grid.

```
Vector2 imagePoition = new Vector2(gridPoints[i].X + offsetX, gridPoints[i].Y);
```

If you need to align it along Y-axis do the same with the cell height and image height